# Why did I get "Use of unassigned local variable" error?

Tags: c#, version-control

I tried to do a simple thing and it gave me an error. The error is:

> Use of unassigned local variable "answer"

Where did I go wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1

{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int l;
        int w;
        int h;
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter th points");
        Console.Write("Length: ");
        l = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Width: ");
        w = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Height: ");
        h = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int answer;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter what you want to Do [S,P,V]");
        string cupSize = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (cupSize)
        {
            case "s":
                answer = (l * w);
                break;
            case "S":
                answer = (l * w);
                break;
            case "p":
                answer = ((l + w) * 2);
                break;
            case "P":
                answer = ((l + w) * 2);
                break;
            case "v":
                answer = (l * w * h);
                break;
            case "V":
                answer = (l * w * h);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Try agian");
                break;
        }

        if (answer != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The answer is " + answer );
        } 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: bla bla bla? Change to `int answer = 0;`

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you can stack the `cases` so you don't have to duplicate the code. `case "s":` `case "S":` `answer = (l*w);` `break;`. Or optionally convert the input to lower case and check that case.

Comment: You are initializing 'answer' but 'default' in your switch statement does not assign it to anything.

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the value of `answer` in every possible code path, but if your `switch`-block goes to the `default` case, it won't be set.

Either set the value at the time it's declared:

```
int answer = 0;
```

Or in your `default` case:

```
default:
    answer = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Try agian");
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error is trying to tell you, that variable does not necessarily have a value.

If your code hits the `default:` case, it won't get assigned.

Answer (score 1):

you need set answer variable try this

```
int answer = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set an int that is uninitialized.

Set `int answer = 0;`

Comment: If I just write "int answer." So it null?
Ok thank you, I did not think about it

Comment: p.s.w.g's answer noting the issue is that if the default case results, 'answer' will not be assigned a value, is the most correct answer.

Comment: @user2770428 The default value for an `int` is 0, but that's not the issue here. C# ***requires*** you to provide a value for a variable along every code path before you use it, even if it's only the default value.

Comment: @Richard There is a typo in your answer. Actually, the error is that OP is trying to *use* the int, not *set* it.